# How to create a query in Firebase in sections (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
{
  "products": {
      "product001": {
          "category": "Drinks",
          "title": "Antarctic Beer",
          "subtitle": "600ml"
      },
      "product002": {
          "category": "Drinks",
          "title": "Smirnoff Ice",
          "subtitle": ""
      },
      "product003": {
          "category": "Drinks",
          "title": "Red Label",
          "subtitle": "12 years"
      }
   }
}
```

Based on the above structure, how to create a query (Firebase) using the "category" as section in Tableview and other fields in the cell?

Product.Swift (model)

```
import Foundation
```

class Categories: NSObject {

```
// MARK: -  Instance variables

var category: String?
var listProducts: [Products]

init(title: String, itens: [Products]) {

    self.category = title
    self.listProducts = itens
}
```

}

class Products: NSObject {

```
var idProduct: String!
var titleProduct: String!
var subTitleProduct: String!

init(key: String, dictionary: Dictionary <String, AnyObject>) {

    super.init()

    self.idProduct = key

    if let titleDictionary = dictionary["title"] as? String { self.titleProduct = titleDictionary }
    if let subTitleDictionary = dictionary["subtitle"] as? String { self.subTitleProduct = subTitleDictionary }
}
```

}

ViewController.swift (custom query function)

```
func queryProducts() {

    self.categoryList.removeAll()

    ref.child("products").observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        let snapshots = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]

        if snapshots == nil {

            print("Not found...")

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "No registered product.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {

            var category = String?()

            for snap in snapshots! {

                category = snap.0

                var productList = [Products]() {
                    didSet {

                        print("PRODUCTS LIST : \(productList)")
                    }
                }

                self.ref.child("products").child(category!).observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot2) in

                    let snapshots2 = snapshot2.value as? [String: AnyObject]

                    productList.removeAll()

                    for snap2 in snapshots2! {

                        let produtKey = snap2.0
                        if let productValue = snap2.1 as? Dictionary <String, AnyObject> {

                            let products = Products(key: produtKey, dictionary: productValue)
                            productList.insert(products, atIndex: productList.count)


                        } else {

                            print("ERRO")
                        }
                    }
                })

                let category2 = Categories(title: category!, itens: productList)

                self.categoryList.insert(category2, atIndex: self.categoryList.count)
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

I managed to get to this point, but for some reason (to my beginner knowledge) i'm not getting the list (dictionary) products into the Category list ...

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Also there is no 'gender' in the posted structure - perhaps you mean genre? Also, Swift or ObjC? Lastly, what have you tried? Can you post a snippet of your Firebase Observe/Query code?

Comment: Yes, that same "genre" I'm programming in Swift. I tried this code, but is not responding as I hope.

Comment: If you want to return nodes based on specific data, 'comedy' in this example, you would perform a .child("genre").queryEqualToValue('comedy') in your observe. That will filter the nodes to return just those nodes that match comedy . There's a great example on the Firebase website ["Work with Lists"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) in the section Filtering Data.